# Pip and easy_install installing in different directories?

Tags: python, macos, pip

On OSX.
When I install any package using `pip` (i.e. `pylint`) the executable is not placed in `/usr/local/bin/pylint` and the module is not importable.

When I install using `easy_install`, the module is placed in
`/Users/username/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pylint`

Interestingly, `numpy` and a whole bunch of other packages, have been installed in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`

I'm just trying to figure out why `pip` installed packages don't work (when I try `pip install pylint`, it says it's already installed, but I cannot find it in either directories, nor import it as a module)

Comment: Have you installed a second Python 2.7 (from python.org, or anaconda, or Homebrew) in addition to the pre-installed Apple one? If so, most likely, your `pip` is installing for that second Python 2.7, while `easy_install` is installing for the Apple one.

Comment: I don't think so - `which python` produces `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: If `/usr/bin` is higher on your PATH than `/usr/local/bin` or `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`, then `which python` will show `/usr/bin/python`. That doesn't at all prove that you have no second Python, or that your `pip` is for that second Python.

Comment: $PATH is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`
No other python2.X in `/usr/local/bin/`